# Gateaux Differentiation in Infinite Dimensional Space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces. A mapping $F: X\rightarrow Y$ is said to be Gateaux differentiable at $x_0\in X$ iff there exists a **continuous linear** mapping $A: X\rightarrow Y$ such that
$$
\textbf{(*)} \quad \lim_{t\downarrow 0}\frac{F(x_0+th)-F(x_0)}{t}=A(h) \quad \forall h\in X.
$$
I would like to construct a **nonlinear** mapping $F: X\rightarrow Y$ that is not Gateaux differentiable at  $x_0\in X$ but there exists a **discontinuous linear** mapping $A: X\rightarrow Y$ such that **(*)** is satisfied.

Thank you for all comments and helping.

Comment: Can we cheat taking $F$ linear and discontinuous?

Comment: Davide Giraudo: Yeah. You are right. How about $F$ is nonlinear? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: And with $F^2$, where $F$ is linear and discontinuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $X$ an infinite dimensional Banach space, and $Y:=\Bbb R$. There exists a non-continuous linear functional $f$. Let $F(x):=f(x)^2$ and let $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\neq 0$. Then 
\begin{align}
F(x_0+th)-F(x_0)&=(f(x_0)+tf(h))^2-f(x_0)^2\\
&=2tf(x_0)f(h)+t^2f(x_0)^2,
\end{align}
so the $A$ which would work is $A(h):=2f(x_0)f(h)$, which is not continuous.